# Why won't my Ext.Window size itself to fit a Ext.Panel subclass?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

In my app, I'm trying to place a subclass of Ext.Panel in a Ext.Window. The Panel can potentially get bigger at run-time as more items are added to it, so I want the Window to dynamically size itself to fit the Panel. I also want the Window to only grow up to a max width and height and then autoScroll after that. Below I've substituted `MockPanel` for my real one to try to make things simpler. `MockPanel` just contains the Google logo image.

```
var MockPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    autoRender: true,
    html:"<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'/>"
});

var window = new Ext.Window({
    header: false,
    border: false,
    closable: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    frame: false,
    layout:"fit",
    boxMaxHeight: 400,
    boxMaxWidth: 1000,
    autoScroll: true,
    items : [
        new MockPanel()
    ]
});

window.show();
```

When I run this code I wind up getting a Window with no width and almost no height, but what I want is for it to automatically be big enough to accommodate `MockPanel`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS can't magically know the size of your MockPanel - you either have to set the size directly or calculate it from the size of the image you're loading. For example, this works:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var MockPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
        html: "<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'/>",
        width: 538,
        height: 190
    });

    var window = new Ext.Window({
        layout: "fit",
        items: [
            new MockPanel()
        ]
    });

    window.show();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding 'layout: "fit", to MockPanel